# How to override this virtual operator in c++?

Tags: c++, class

Base struct is defined like this in the header file:

```
struct Base {
    virtual operator char * (void) {
        return 0;
    }
    virtual operator long (void) {      // hash function
        return 0;
    }
    virtual long operator == (Base & base) {// isequal function
        return *this == base;
    }
    Base (void) {}              // new_element
    virtual ~Base (void) {}         // delete_element
    virtual ostream & Write (ostream & stream) = 0;// write_element
};
```

I am confused by the first two virtual operator declarations, suppose I have a new class inherits the base class, how do I override these two operators so that when the subclass object is regarded as the Base class, these two functions can be called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like any other function that you override.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    virtual operator char * (void) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

struct B : A
{
    operator char * (void) override
    {
        return (char*)12;
    }
};

struct C : A
{
    operator char * (void) override
    {
        return (char*)24;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    vector<A*> v;
    v.push_back(new A);
    v.push_back(new B);
    v.push_back(new C);

    for (auto e : v)
    {
        char* p = *e;
        cout << "p=" << (int)p << endl;
    }

    for (auto e : v)
    {
        delete e;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will print:

```
p=0
p=12
p=24
```

Comment: Thanks! The typecast overloading is new to me.